# Sax parser throwing fatal error on Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I get the HTML string from webservice.

[image]

When I parse on saxparser, it throws fatal error1.

Start tag (Image tag) doesn't match with end tag. Then how to get image src? And how to get div id name? Or is there any other parser to parse HTML string? Please help me.

Comment: html != xml. You need a valid xml to parse it via Sax/DOM parsers.

Comment: friend thanks for info. then how to get the content on the html tag.

Comment: probably just try to cut out the url substring "manually" from the html string using `String.indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` and `String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing HTML is a non-trivial problem, made more difficult on BlackBerry smartphones by the limitations of J2ME. I have a [blog posting on leveraging the BrowserField to parse the HTML](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2011/08/parsing-html-on-blackberry.html), which will then give you a DOM document. It solved my problem, something similar may work for you.

Comment: Hi. i parse the html string using browserfieldlistener when document loading. Successfully get the content.  But below os 5.0 no browserfield listener. What should do. pls help me.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no easy solution prior to BlackBerry OS 5. You will have to either require OS 5, or use other more fragile methods. If you have control over the source html the best solution is to require that it be fully XML complient.