# How to use html parser in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

How to use html parser in blackberry?

Any example of html parser in android

```
Html.fromHtml(tmpHtml).toString()
```

If I can use this method in blackberry how can I use this method and parse html string.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333512/431639) of the question [Sax parser throwing fatal error on Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330050/sax-parser-throwing-fatal-error-on-blackberry).

There is a link to an article, [Parsing HTML on Blackberry](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2011/08/parsing-html-on-blackberry.html). It might be helpful.